# Using ScikitLearn TfidfVectorizer in a search engine

Tags: python, scikit-learn, search-engine, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I'm looking at creating a search engine were I can fetch sentences (which represente a document) from a preprocessed pdf file using keywords.

I'm wondering if there is a built-in function in scikit-learn to show the data similarly to a bag of word output, meaning I'd have all the words as columns (in pandas), all documents as rows, and the tf-idf values as values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do it in toy problems and for educational purposes only, but it is completely **impractical** and **highly not advisable** for real ones.

The reason is that such term-document matrices are *sparse* (i.e. most of their entries are actually 0's), and this sparsity is used for their efficient storage in appropriate data structures. Converting them to non-sparse structures (i.e. pandas dataframes) would most probably overwhelm the memory of your machine; quoting from the relevant scikit-learn [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#sparsity):

> As most documents will typically use a very small subset of the words
>   used in the corpus, the resulting matrix will have many feature values
>   that are zeros (typically more than 99% of them).
>
> For instance a collection of 10,000 short text documents (such as
>   emails) will use a vocabulary with a size in the order of 100,000
>   unique words in total while each document will use 100 to 1000 unique
>   words individually.
>
> In order to be able to store such a matrix in memory but also to speed
>   up algebraic operations matrix / vector, implementations will
>   typically use a sparse representation such as the implementations
>   available in the `scipy.sparse` package.

That said, you can do it for educational purposes; here is how, adapting the example in the `TfidfVectorizer` [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd

corpus = [
...     'This is the first document.',
...     'This document is the second document.',
...     'And this is the third one.',
...     'Is this the first document?',
... ]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

df = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(X, columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names())
df
# result:


    and         document    first       is          one         second      the         third       this
0   0.000000    0.469791    0.580286    0.384085    0.000000    0.000000    0.384085    0.000000    0.384085
1   0.000000    0.687624    0.000000    0.281089    0.000000    0.538648    0.281089    0.000000    0.281089
2   0.511849    0.000000    0.000000    0.267104    0.511849    0.000000    0.267104    0.511849    0.267104
3   0.000000    0.469791    0.580286    0.384085    0.000000    0.000000    0.384085    0.000000    0.384085
```

Comment: Indeed, I didn't take the memory problem into account. I'll try some other route to extract the information I want without using the whole matrix. However, thanks a lot for the example ! I didn't know this function.

Answer (score 0):

You have in scikit learn [TfIdfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer) and [TfIdfTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer).

The result is the one you need, with the following difference between them :

TfIdfVectorizer takes raw documents in input.

TfIdfTransformer takes a matrix with work counts per document, in input.